# How to enable internationalization? (translations)

Tags: customization

I would like to know if there is a German translation of Blender.

Answer (score 3):

In User preferences (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>), under System check `International Fonts`, select your language (German is available, I just checked), and mark the parts you want to translate (`Interface`, `Tooltips` and `New Data`).

[image]